# How to configure WCF to handle lots of concurrent users?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wcf, azure

We are developing a multi-tenant system which is utilizing WCF + SQL Azure for data access. Basically we have WCF service hosted in Azure to which our client connects and then this WCF service queries SQL database for data and returns data to client. Everything else is working just fine but we have some odd performance problems with channel between client and WCF.

It seems that if there are enough concurrent users using our service, WCF will start to block connections. And by "enough" I mean something like 20-30 users which are making approximately 1 query per second, which in turn should be something that I would expect WCF to be able to handle without problems. The time spent in WCF service per query is less than 1 second, usually 100 to 200ms.

The reasons why we believe WCF is blocking connections are:

1. We are logging both time spent in WCF service and the time that
   WCF call takes in total, and there is substantial difference between
   these. For example, time spent in WCF service could be 100ms and the
   total time (from client's perspective) could be 5000ms or even
   10000ms.
2. Client could be running just fine until it hits first
   spike. Subsequential calls will either take very long time or even
   time out.
3. Sometimes client cannot connect to service at all.

WCF service is using netTcpBinding and following settings are configured:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1024;
netTcpBinding.MaxConnections = 1024;
netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = 5 minutes
netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = 5 minutes
serviceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1024;
serviceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = 1024;
serviceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = 1024;
```

I'm not sure if this is important but all clients are behind same IP address. Also, channel is opened and closed for each request (mostly because Azure closes connections after they have been idle for 1 minute and we haven't been able to figure out how to handle this in robust way).

Any ideas?

Following questions are related to this but they really don't provide an answer:
[How to scale SQL azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123400/how-to-scale-sql-azure)
[SQL Azure vs WCF Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952780/sql-azure-vs-wcf-performance)

Comment: I would look at how you have WCF configured.  Take SQL out by just by just returning some static results. See the links in this answer.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746424/wcf-operationcontract-tuning-instancing-and-concurrency-with-tsql

Comment: Is your service configured as PerCall, PerSession or Singleton?

Comment: @Blam, we have already taken SQL out (even simple ping method that sleep for 100ms causes the problem)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, we're using default values so it is PerSession and concurrency mode is Single

Comment: You have a concurrency mode of Single and you wonder why it does not scale?  Single means one instance responding to all requests.

Comment: @Blam, it's single per _session_, meaning that one instance of service is created for each TCP connection. To be more clear, _instance mode_ is PerSession (_not_ single) but concurrency mode is _single_

Comment: Exactly concurrency is set to single and you wonder why it does not scale.

Comment: @Blma, No, it does not work that way, just take a look of that WCF Throttling link below. Yes it means that single service instance does not allow concurrent calls but _every session_ (in this case, TCP connection) _has its own service instance_.

Comment: Really, if that is how it works then why is it not working for you?

Comment: @Blam, that's exactly why I asked this question in the first place! However, after some investigation it seems that the problem is actually related more to Azure than to WCF itself.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Diagnostics in WCF, it will help you identify problems.

Take a look once again to your throttling config again:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114(v=vs.100).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33362/WCF-Throttling

In case you are transfering large objects, change the default TransferMode to Streammed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look about diagnostics and those links, and report back if it solved problem